# How to add a Google Search Box to search results?

Tags: google, google-search, search-results

I would like to add a search box to the Google search results, just like Stack Overflow [seen here](https://www.google.co.in/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=stack%20overflow). I have been trying for several days but no luck. How can I add this to my own site?

Answer (score 0):

Here's the code for google search.

```
<!-- Use of this code assumes agreement with the Google Custom Search Terms of Service. -->
<!-- The terms of service are available at http://www.google.com//cse/docs/tos.html -->
<form name="cse" id="searchbox_demo" action="https://www.google.com/cse">
  <input type="hidden" name="cref" value="" />
  <input type="hidden" name="ie" value="utf-8" />
  <input type="hidden" name="hl" value="" />
  <input name="q" type="text" size="40" />
  <input type="submit" name="sa" value="Search" />
</form>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https%3A%2F%2Fcse.google.com%2Fcse/tools/onthefly?form=searchbox_demo&lang="></script>
```